# Dataconfig - is there a limit on number of sub-entities with in an entity?

Tags: solr, classnotfoundexception, dataimporthandler

I came across this bizarre issue.

In my dataconfig file, I have a root entity and 15 other sub-entities with in it. If I try to do full-import, the following error occurs.

Error log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select fruitName from fruits     where id = '2'      Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:252)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:209)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:472)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:498)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:411)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load null or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.null
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:899)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:159)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:362)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:239)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:385)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:889)
    ... 18 more
```

If I execute the query in error log against my database, I dont find any errors.
I tried swapping the order of entities. Each time in the error log, I find the query of the last entity.

But if I remove a random entity the full-import succeeds.

Is this due to some sort of limit imposed on number of sub-entities/ fields?
Why is it trying to load class "null"? Am I missing anything?

Any help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Layout of my dataconfig.xml:

```
<dataconfig>
<document>

<entity name = "outer_entity" query="select id from outerTable">

   <entity name = "subEntity1" query="select value1 from subEntity1">
   </entity>

   <entity name = "subEntity2" query="select value2 from subEntity2">
   </entity>

   ..........

   <entity name = "subEntity14" query="select value14 from subEntity14">
   </entity>

   <entity name = "subEntity15" query="select value15 from subEntity15">
   </entity>

</entity>

</document>
</dataconfig>
```

Comment: Does the query return any rows? select fruitName from fruits     where id = '2'

Comment: No.. there is no rows returned, as there is no entry for id = '2' in fruits table..

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Can you try select NVL(fruitName, '') from fruits where id = '2' instead of the one you are using?

Comment: I tried it.. but the process fails again..

Comment: Can you help me with the data-config.xml file?

Comment: I have shared the layout of my dataconfig.xml file...

Comment: I have not come across a limit to sub entities. However in your case it looks evident because if you remove 1 entity it works. I would suggest you to join the query somehow or use a view.

Comment: Thanks for your help Junaid! As a quick temporary work around, I was also thinking about the same.. But it still annoys me!

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across a limit to sub entities. However in your case it looks evident because if you remove 1 entity it works.

I would suggest you to join the query somehow or use a view.